# How to modify function below to get events from multiple calendars

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am using the below function to extract events from Google Calendar to Google Sheet, is there a way to modify this to extract events from multiple calendars.

```
function getEvents () {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID").getSheetByName("Cal");
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("username@email.ca");
   var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("4/1/2022 12:00 AM"), new Date("4/30/2022 11:59 PM"));

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 5).clearContent();

  
  for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
    var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
    var loc = events[i].getLocation();
    var des = events[i].getDescription();
    
    ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(sd);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm AM/PM")
    ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(ed);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm AM/PM")
    ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setValue(title);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(loc);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(des);
 
 } 
  
}
```

Comment: Loop through all of the calendars. Calendar Id's ['id1','id2'....].forEach(id => { cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id)})

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
function getEvents() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  if (lr > 0) {
    ss.getRange(2, 1, lr - 1, 5).clearContent();
  }
  const ids = ['q289qp9augtnshkn70dkibcc54@group.calendar.google.com', 'jimesteban@jimesteban.com'];//cal ids
  ids.forEach(id => {
    let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
    let events = cal.getEvents(new Date("4/23/2022 8:00 AM"), new Date("4/23/2022 5:00 PM"));
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var title = events[i].getTitle();
      var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
      var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
      var loc = events[i].getLocation();
      var des = events[i].getDescription();
      ss.appendRow([sd,ed,title,loc,des])
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: hey @Cooper this script is pulling events only for the last calendar ID provided in line 5
for example, in this case it is only pulling events for id2,

`const ids = ['id1', 'id2'];//cal ids`

Comment: this script clears content from all rows and starts adding new rows from the last blank row instead of clearing content and starting in second row, how to fix that?

Comment: You question was about getting events from multiple calendars.  I provided a solution for that and left the remaining part of the script alone.  If you have another question feel free to post another question.